# How to execute the version of R which installed in a local folder?

Tags: r, statistics

I unpacked the new version of R package and inside a folder I gave commands:

```
./configure
make
```

Now I want to run it, if I give command:

```
$ R
```

Then it runs the older version. and I have no privilege to deal with it. so I want to run the new installed version. any help?
Perhaps it needs to be exported but i am not familiar with these steps. 
thanks

Comment: Do you have a `bin` folder within the directory that you performed the installation?

Comment: yes I have bin folder in the directory

Comment: Great- I posted it as an answer below, which you can accept using the green checkmark if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To execute the new version of R, run `bin/R` within the installation directory.

To move it to a globally accessible location, run

```
make install
```

If you don't have permission to do so (as you indicate), you can alter the directory that `make install` moves `R` to to one where you do have permission at the `./configure` step:

```
./configure --prefix=/where/you/want/R/to/go
make
make install
```